# What is the lambda expression to inner join a set of IDs to a split comma separated list of IDs from a sting?

Tags: linq, lambda

I'm passing a list of IDs into a method as a comma separated string (StateIDs). In the method I want to filter CountyID by StateID by inner joining the split of StateIDs to County.StateID.

I can't seem to get the syntax correct and would appreciate some help figuring this out.

```
public IQueryable<County> GetCounty(string StateIDs = null)
{
    var county = _repo.GetCounties();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StateIDs))
    {
        county = county.Join(StateIDs.Split(',').ToList(), x => x.StateID, y => Convert.ToInt32(y), (x, y) => x).ToList();
    }
    return county;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are neither showing much effort, nor providing sufficient detail for the question to be answered. Pleae provide the specifc error you are getting, and some of the attempts you have made to reduce the problem scope as part of debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
public IQueryable<County> GetCounty(string StateIDs = null)
{
    var county = _repo.GetCounties();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StateIDs))
    {
        // the ids as a list of integer
        var ids = StateIds.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s));

        // use .Contains
        county = county.Where(c => ids.Contains(c.StateID));
    }

    return county;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I was doing a join, which was resulting in duplicate rows. You also straightened out the order of events: split, then convert to int, then use contains. Thank you.